# CFNetwork.Connection crashed

Tags: ios

My iOS app had a crash caused by CFNetwork. I cannot reproduce it. The app was running on iOS 12. I am using Alamofire to perform HTTP requests, but I don't think it was caused by Alamofire. Anyone has any idea?

```
Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.Connection
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1ba289104 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ba308a00 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 296
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1ba1e0d78 abort + 140
3  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1ba1ae67c basename_r + 314
4  CFNetwork                      0x1bae63478 invocation function for block in TCPIOConnection::_tlsValidateServerTrust(nw_tls_context*) + 346
5  CFNetwork                      0x1bae614e0 TCPIOConnection::_handleTLSEvent(nw_tls_context*, tls_handshake_message_t, void () block_pointer, bool) + 720
6  libnetwork.dylib               0x1bb8716b0 __tcp_connection_set_tls_message_handler_on_nw_connection_block_invoke + 168
7  libboringssl.dylib             0x1bb5e505c __boringssl_context_issue_tls_handshake_callback_block_invoke + 188
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba12b6c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba12c484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba106fb0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 548
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba107b2c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 468
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba108d70 _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1892
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ba10ff14 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ba30e0f0 _pthread_wqthread + 312
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1ba310d00 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: having similar crash logs from firebase in my production version

Comment: any luck to resolve this?